# Leer bits de byte

Tags: c#

Haciendo un programa hecho con Windows Form bajo .Net FrameWotk 4.7. Si envío un comando por el puerto serie que se llama X82, recibo un mensaje que en ASCII no se entiende porque usa caracteres raros.

Lo paso a hexadecimal y en binario.

Envío un comando, ocurre algún evento y en Windoes Form me aparece cógios en HEX y en BIN. Se puede cambiar varios bit en un único Byte.

Por ejemplo, si me llega este dato.

```
**Hexadecimal:** 23C797C0B00D

**Binario:** 00100011 11000111 10010111 11000000 10110000 00001101
```

Un ejemplo, es poner muchos labels en cada bits y una tabla de cada Byte recibido. Simpre son la misma cantidad de bytes ya que en realdiad hace de Flags.

Centrándonos en el binario, ya que hay 6 Bytes.

```
00100011 11000111 10010111 11000000 10110000 00001101
-------- -------- -------- -------- -------- --------
 Byte I  Byte a    Byte b   Byte c   Byte d   Byte F
```

En el Byte c que corresponde al 11000000 quiero leer el bit 3 que corresponde al "Extractor" indicado en la tabla de abajo. Cada Byte tiene su tabla, ahora nos centramos en un Byte y ver los estados de los bits.

```
**bit:c Dato        Función.**
7 =   1            Motor A.
6 =   1            Motor B.
5 =   0            Luz A.
4 =   0            Luz B.
3 =   0            Extractor.
2 =   0            Alarma.
1 =   0            Persiana.
0 =   0            Ventilador
```

El Byte c que ahora contiene estos bits que son 11000000, me llega una nueva trama de Bytes y precisamente este, cambia de 11000000 a 11001000. Solo ha cambiado un bit que es el 3 en el Byte c.

Cada bit tiene su label para mostrarlo en el formulario de Windows. La tabla de abajo se actualiza.

```
**bit:c Dato        Función.**
7 =   1            Motor A.
6 =   1            Motor B.
5 =   0            Luz A.
4 =   0            Luz B.
3 =   1            Extractor.
2 =   0            Alarma.
1 =   0            Persiana.
0 =   0            Ventilador
```

Antes el Byte c del bit 3 que es el Extractor estaba a 0, ahora es 1.

En resumen.
Quiero saber como se leen los bits que me llegan del puerto serie.

¿Existe la posibilidad de hacer un programa así?

Saludos.

Comment: Creo que quiere el "bitwise AND" con el simbolo &.  Por ejemplo para bits 7 y 8 de un byte, es  respuesta = foo & 0x11000000   Si la respuesta está más de 0, los bits están puestos.  https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators

Comment: Buenas: Estuve mirando las AND y ejemplos. Mi objetivo es que al recibir datos en ASCII, pasarlo a Hex y luego a binario. Al pasarlo al binaro por ejemplo este: 
**Binario:** 00100011 11000111 10010111 11000000 10110000 00001101
El 4º Byte que es el Byte c que contiene 8 bits, solo quiero cambiar, solo se me cambia el bit 3 a estado 0 ó 1.
Cada bit de un Byte tiene su propio label.Text o Console.Write() por llamarlo de alguna manera, mostralo en pantalla. Por eso puse ejemplo de la tabla de arriba. Gracias.
Cada actualización de un bit de algunos de los 6 Bytes, viene en 6 Bytes en 6 Bytes